Navigation and routing in SAP BusinessOne UI API extension app web client
I am developing a SAP BusinessOne UI API extension for web SAP B1 webclient. I have two UDO views in this app. The requirement is on a button click from UDO1 view, need to navigate to the UDO2 view. From there we need to select some data from the UDO2 view and navigate back to UDO1 view. In the UI API extension documentation, the method available is
await oEnv.open("/webx/index.html#webclient-ORDR&/Objects/ORDR/List");

but this will open the url as an external link.
Is it possible to implement the navigation to other views just like SAPUI5 apps in SAP B1 UI API extensions?
Is any documentation available for the routing and navigation between pages in SAP Business One web client?
Thanks,
Deepesh
